# Refreshing QTableView based on data refreshed periodically via QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm trying to refresh a `QTableView` based on data from a method `get_data` which is called periodically by `QTimer` as below.
Once I get the data, I update it in my model (via a member function `refresh`) and then call `refresh_table` to hopefully update the `tableView` with the current data. However, the call to `tableView->update()` (I've also tried `tableView->repaint()`) does not work as intended, and `tableView` does not update - staying put at its first-call value. Note that my data is liable to change completely, and it's not simply a matter of inserting extra rows.

```
void MainWindow::DataDisplay(QWidget *tab) {
    auto tableView = create_table(tab,...);
    auto timer = new QTimer(this);
    auto model = new MyModel();
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [tableView, model, this]() {
        const auto data = get_data();
        model->refresh(data);
        refresh_table(model, tableView);

    });
    timer->start(1000);
}
```

```
auto refresh_table(MyModel *model,
                   QTableView *tableView) {
    tableView->setModel(model);
    tableView->update(); // does not work
}
```

What's the canonical way of refreshing one's model in `Qt` such that the associated `TableView` is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is for your model to emit a [dataChanged()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal.  Any associated QTableViews will receive that signal and respond by re-querying the model for new values and updating the associated cells of their table.